# How to throttle this api request using lodash in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, asynchronous, lodash

I am using React and trying to figure out how to implement the lodash debounce method to throttle the api request. I have tried to implement it based on examples on the internet but seems like it doesn't work in this case.  And it is supposed to wait about 3 seconds before the api method gets called again based on the `amountValue`, which is basically a state value. Here is my code which I am trying to throttle the api request.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const [amountValue, setAmountValue] = useState('');

  const handleGetSwapPrice = useCallback(() => {
    getFinalPrice(amountValue)
      .then((res) => {
        const formattedPrice = formatCurrency('USD', res.price);
        if (!res.price) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
        setSwapPrice(formattedPrice);
      });
  }, [baseAsset, quoteAsset, transactionType]);


  useEffect(() => {
      handleGetSwapPrice();
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using lodash for debounce, you have to create a debounced version of the function using useCallback hook. If your are using it in Input field, please provide the debounced function inside handleChange.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const [amountValue, setAmountValue] = useState('');

  const handleGetSwapPrice = () => {
    getFinalPrice(amountValue)
      .then((res) => {
        const formattedPrice = formatCurrency('USD', res.price);
        if (!res.price) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
        setSwapPrice(formattedPrice);
      });
  }

  const debouncedAPICall = useCallback(debounce((e) => handleGetSwapPrice(e), 3000), []);

  useEffect(() => {
      debouncedAPICall();
    }
  }, []);
```